# How to overwrite ng-click functionality

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to take a form button that says `Save` to change to `Saving...` when it's busy.  It'd be awesome if this could detect that there's an ng-click directive here and only trigger that directive if `busy` is false.  Would I need to create a new directive for this, or is there a way to just tap into ng-click's functionality?

HTML:

`<button-large color="green" ng-click="createWorkstation()" busy="disableSave()" busyLabel="Saving...">Save</button-large>`

JS:

```
directive('buttonLarge', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            busy: '&'
        },
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<button type="checkbox" class="buttonL" ng-transclude/>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var config = {
                color: "Default"
            };

            angular.extend(config, attrs);

            element.addClass("b"+capitalize(config.color));

            //when the button is busy, disable the button
            scope.$watch(attrs.busy, function () {
                console.log('changed', scope.busy);
            });

            //capitalize first letter of string
            function capitalize(s) {
                return s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1);
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Instead of that, why don't you take a simple approach - hide the Save button when the user clicks on it and show the Saving... button. Inside the function called for the `ng-click`, set a model that will show or hide the Save button (and hide and show the Saving button) until the save is complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just do it like this:

```
<button ng-click="createWorkstation()">{{isBusy && "Saving" || "Save"}} </button>
```

Where isBusy can just be a boolean that you are changing in your scope (or a function I guess) while you are processing/etc.  This doesn't require a directive and keeps the wording in the markup.  You could probably extend this to having a service  or constant for the strings/etc but that just depends on how far you want to take it.

** update **

If you want to bind html per one of the comments you'd use the `ng-bind-html-unsafe` directive:

```
<button ng-click="go()" ng-bind-html-unsafe="isBusy && '<span class=icol-refresh></span><span>Saving...</span>' || 'Save'">Process</button>
```

Comment: Thanks... that's insanely simple compared to what I was trying to do ^_^

Comment: Though as a note... this doesn't work: `{{disableSave() && "<span class='icol-refresh'></span><span>Saving...</span>" || "Save"}}`  The span tags conflict with the `<span class='ng-scope'>` tag

Comment: If you want to use the span, you'll need to use the ng-bind-html-unsafe directive.  Here is an example:  http://plnkr.co/edit/uBZFFMjhhdVuWg1Jgeej?p=preview